# How to include pdfpage with subsection written on top?

Tags: pdfpages

I am using pdfpages package and I have a 3 page document of pdf I want to insert into my main document. But the problem is I can't get the subsection heading to show on the top of the page before the pdf file is inserted ONLY ONCE. I used pagecommand but what that does is for everypage it writes out the subsection at the top. Here is the code im using 
Here is the code I am using

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
...
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\subsection{List of use cases}]{SE2.pdf}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a command that inserts a section head then redefines itself to do nothing:

```
\def\mysect{%
\subsection{List of use cases}%
\gdef\mysect{}}


\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\mysect]{SE2.pdf}
```